# Spring Boot FeignClient with Image response give error 'stream is closed'

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-boot

My Spring REST controller which uses FeignClient for consuming another Image/Blob storage microservice fails with error 'stream is closed'.  whats the proper way to consume blob data service.

REST Controller

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/blob")
public class BlobDataRestController  extends BaseRESTController{

    @Autowired
    private IBlobService blobService;

    @CrossOrigin
    @RequestMapping(value = "/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@PathVariable(value = "filename") String filename){
        return blobService.getFile(filename);
    }
}
```

FeignClient interface

```
@FeignClient(name="blob-service", url="${blob-service.url}")
public interface IBlobService {

     @RequestMapping(value = "/blob/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> getFile(@PathVariable(value = "filename") String filename);
}
```

Error when invoking the microservice */blob/filename.jpg*

```
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT 2016-07-27 15:01:41.732 ERROR 29 --- [io-61779-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT java.io.IOException: stream is closed
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.ensureOpen(HttpURLConnection.java:3309) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(HttpURLConnection.java:3334) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:133) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.io.PushbackInputStream.read(PushbackInputStream.java:186) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(FilterInputStream.java:107) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.util.StreamUtils.copy(StreamUtils.java:126) ~[spring-core-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:102) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.http.converter.ResourceHttpMessageConverter.writeInternal(ResourceHttpMessageConverter.java:47) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.http.converter.AbstractHttpMessageConverter.write(AbstractHttpMessageConverter.java:195) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.writeWithMessageConverters(AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor.java:238) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.HttpEntityMethodProcessor.handleReturnValue(HttpEntityMethodProcessor.java:183) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.handleReturnValue(HandlerMethodReturnValueHandlerComposite.java:81) ~[spring-web-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:126) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:832) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:743) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:961) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
2016-07-27T20:31:41.73+0530 [App/0]      OUT    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:967) ~[spring-webmvc-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar!/:4.2.6.RELEASE]
```

Comment: Have you tried retrieving it as a `byte[]`? Holding open a stream is the sort of thing that could get tricky under any sort of load.

Comment: Yes I did,  was trying to return the byte[] and didn't work.  Haven't tried on saving temporary on disk,  don't want to add additional delay on returning the image

Answer (score 21):

If I use ResponseEntity with byte[] as response, everything is working perfectly:

```
@FeignClient(name="blob-service", url="${blob-service.url}")
public interface IBlobService {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/blob/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public ResponseEntity<byte[]> getFile(@PathVariable(value = "filename") String filename);
}
```

But it may cause OutOfMemoryError, so I've made an investigation and found  better solution:

```
@FeignClient(name="blob-service", url="${blob-service.url}")
public interface IBlobService {
     @RequestMapping(value = "/blob/{filename:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
     public feign.Response getFile(@PathVariable(value = "filename") String filename);
}
```

And I'm working with blobService in a such way:

```
try (Response response = blobService.getFile(fileName)) {
    InputStream is = response.body().asInputStream();
  // work with is
}
```

Also I found in [Feign sources](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/9.3.1/core/src/main/java/feign/SynchronousMethodHandler.java#L120-L124) that response.body().asInputStream() returns original sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveStream if response size is over than 8192 bytes

```
if (response.body().length() == null ||
            response.body().length() > MAX_RESPONSE_BUFFER_SIZE) {
    shouldClose = false;
    return response;
}
```

Otherwise feign.Response.ByteArrayBody will be created. And if you try to access InputStream [it will return ByteArrayInputStream](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/blob/9.3.1/core/src/main/java/feign/Response.java#L357-L359).
That all stuff solves possible OutOfMemoryError.